# Custom bibliography style changes in-text references

Tags: bibtex, xetex

After successfully creating a customized bibliography style, my in-text references has changed from (A & B 2018) to (A and B, 2018), while I want it to be showed as (A en B 2018), with the Dutch language package. I don't understand why it is changed, while I did not write any code to do so. And how it can be changed into 'en' instead of 'and' and how to get rid of the comma.

The library style is a changed version of the `agsm`-style, see this question: [Customise Harvard referencing style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426517/customise-harvard-referencing-style).

MWEB:

```
documentclass{article}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author = {Author, A. and Writer, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  volume = {1},
  journal = {Journal},
  number={2},
  pages={131--143}
}
\end{filecontents}

\let\origharvardyearright\harvardyearright
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\harvardyearright{\origharvardyearright\@ifnextchar,\@gobble\empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text...
\citep{key}

\bibliographystyle{eur}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` directive? Are you using biblatex after all?

Comment: @Mico I used this MWEB example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to reproduce the issue. This MWEB succeeds in that matter, but maybe that line of code is redundant?

Comment: @Nino At least on my system the given MWEB fails because `\addbibresource` is undefined. If this does not lead to an error for you, you might load `biblatex` somewhere. This should be avoided if you want to use `natbib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`natbib` allows to change the citation style with `\setcitestyle`.
Especially the option `aysep` allows to change the characterbetween the author and year. The `ans` can be changed by defining `\harvardand`.

So you get the desired citation style by adding

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\newcommand\harvardand{et}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: This works indeed to get the citations as they were. But I am also supposed to change the ampersand into an 'en', so in this way I am unable to customize the citation style.

Comment: @Nino Sorry, I edited this now to actually answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, you're my hero today. Feel stupid that I couldn't find this somewhere, despite reading a lot about Tex